# Yocto build: "unable to find a match"

Tags: qt, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I am trying to build a custom QT application. However `bitbake` is unable to find the application, while building `rootfs`.

I tried a number of things:

1. Added `ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN}`
2. Added `FILES_${PN}`
3. Removed `_` and `-` from application name
4. added `IMAGE_INSTALL += qtsimplecalc`. If I remove this, it builds, but the application is missing from `rootfs`.
5. Even github repo. was not getting cloned, so I manually cloned it.

Here is `qtsimplecalc.bb`

```
  SUMMARY = "Qt Simple Calculator Application Recipe"   
  DESCRIPTION = "This recipe builds a Qt project for a simple calculator application."   
  LICENSE = "MIT"   
  LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"   
     
  DEPENDS += "qtbase"   
     
  FILESEXTRAPATHS += "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"   
  FILESEXTRAPATHS += "${THISDIR}/files:"   
     
  #SRC_URI = "https://github.com/vpapadopou/qt-simple-calculator.git"   
  #SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"   
  #SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "1eb04ab58f54c11bffa00262b387aeab5e60ef6b42e3cbf88e23c026eb5c28d5"   
     
  SRC_URI = "file://main.cpp  \   
             file://mainwindow.cpp  \   
             file://mainwindow.h  \   
             file://mainwindow.ui  \   
             file://simpleCalculator.pro  \   
             "   
     
  S = "${WORKDIR}"   
     
  do_install () {   
      install -d ${D}/opt/qtsimplecalc/   
      install -m 0755 simpleCalculator ${D}/opt/qtsimplecalc/   
  }   
     
  FILES_${PN} += "/opt/qtsimplecalc/simpleCalculator"   
  #ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"   
     
  inherit qmake5
```

My directory structure looks like:

```
conf/
    -- layer.conf
  recipes-core/
  recipes-example/
  recipes-project/
  recipes-qt-simple-calc/
    -- qtsimplecalc
        -- files
               -- LICENSE.md  
               -- main.cpp  
               -- mainwindow.cpp  
               -- mainwindow.h  
               -- mainwindow.ui  
               -- README.md  
               -- screenshots  
               -- simpleCalculator.pro                                                                                              
        -- qtsimplecalc.bb                         
  recipes-rpilinux/
```

files directory contains source code from github : `https://github.com/vpapadopou/qt-simple-calculator`

`conf/layer.conf` file:

```
  # We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH    
  BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"    
     
  # We have recipes-* directories, add to BBFILES    
  BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \    
    ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"    
     
  BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "rpilinux"    
  BBFILE_PATTERN_rpilinux = "^${LAYERDIR}/"    
  BBFILE_PRIORITY_rpilinux = "6"    
     
  LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_rpilinux = "mickledore"    
     
  # We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH   
  IMAGE_INSTALL += " qtsimplecalc"
```

Here is the error log:

```
NOTE: ###### Generate rootfs #######   
  NOTE: Executing '/home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr  /bin/createrepo_c --update -q /home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-re  po' ...
  NOTE: Running /home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bi  n/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/  etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/  etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/rootfs --set  opt=logdir=/home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/ho  me/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo makecache --refresh
  DEBUG: DNF version: 4.14.0
  cachedir: /home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/cache/dnf
  Added oe-repo repo from /home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
  Making cache files for all metadata files.                                                                                          oe-repo: has expired and will be refreshed.  
  repo: downloading from remote: oe-repo
  oe-repo                                         237 MB/s | 2.3 MB     00:00
  oe-repo: using metadata from Mon 05 Feb 2024 08:20:41 AM UTC.                     
  Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Mon 05 Feb 2024 08:20:41 AM UTC.
  User-Agent: falling back to 'libdnf': could not detect OS or basearch
  Metadata cache created.
  
  NOTE: Running /home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bi  n/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/  etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/  etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/rootfs --set  opt=logdir=/home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/ho  me/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo --nogpgcheck install alsa-lib   alsa-tools alsa-utils bcm2835-dev dbus dhcpcd gstreamer1.0 gstreamer1.0-meta-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ba  se gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-python gstreamer1.0-rtsp-server gstreamer1.0-vaapi hostapd i2c-tools iptables iw libstdc  ++ linux-firmware-rpidistro-bcm43430 linux-firmware-rpidistro-bcm43456 module-init-tools mtd-utils openssh openssh-sftp-server ope  nssl psplash-raspberrypi pulseaudio python3 python3-numpy python3-smbus qt3d qt3d-dev qt3d-mkspecs qtbase qtbase-dev qtbase-mkspec  s qtbase-plugins qtbase-tools qtcharts qtcharts-dev qtcharts-mkspecs qtconnectivity-dev qtconnectivity-mkspecs qtdeclarative qtdec  larative-dev qtdeclarative-mkspecs qtgraphicaleffects qtgraphicaleffects-dev qtquickcontrols2 qtquickcontrols2-dev qtquickcontrols  2-mkspecs qtsimplecalc run-postinsts wpa-supplicant locale-base-c locale-base-en-us locale-base-en-gb                               ERROR: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/reci  pe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpili  nux-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpili  nux-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-i  mage/1.0-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/temp --  repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo --nogp  gcheck install alsa-lib alsa-tools alsa-utils bcm2835-dev dbus dhcpcd gstreamer1.0 gstreamer1.0-meta-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad   gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-python gstreamer1.0-rtsp-server gstreamer1.0-vaapi hostapd i2c-t  ools iptables iw libstdc++ linux-firmware-rpidistro-bcm43430 linux-firmware-rpidistro-bcm43456 module-init-tools mtd-utils openssh   openssh-sftp-server openssl psplash-raspberrypi pulseaudio python3 python3-numpy python3-smbus qt3d qt3d-dev qt3d-mkspecs qtbase   qtbase-dev qtbase-mkspecs qtbase-plugins qtbase-tools qtcharts qtcharts-dev qtcharts-mkspecs qtconnectivity-dev qtconnectivity-mks  pecs qtdeclarative qtdeclarative-dev qtdeclarative-mkspecs qtgraphicaleffects qtgraphicaleffects-dev qtquickcontrols2 qtquickcontr  ols2-dev qtquickcontrols2-mkspecs qtsimplecalc run-postinsts wpa-supplicant locale-base-c locale-base-en-us locale-base-en-gb' ret  urned 1:
  DNF version: 4.14.0
  cachedir: /home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/cache/dnf
  Added oe-repo repo from /home/pranav/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/rpilinux-image/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
  User-Agent: falling back to 'libdnf': could not detect OS or basearch
  repo: using cache for: oe-repo                                                                                                      oe-repo: using metadata from Mon 05 Feb 2024 08:20:41 AM UTC.
  Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Mon 05 Feb 2024 08:20:41 AM UTC.
  No match for argument: qtsimplecalc
  Error: Unable to find a match: qtsimplecalc
  
  DEBUG: Python function do_rootfs finished
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is usually due to an empty package, which means that there is something wrong with your `do_install` that is not installing something in the `${D}` folder which is `${WORKDIR}/image`

The issue is that you are `inherit`ing `qmake5` after you defining your own `do_install` and `qmake5` has its own `do_install` that will run the `install` target on the generated `Makefile` out of your `simpleCalculator.pro` file:

```
####### Install

install:  FORCE

uninstall:  FORCE

FORCE:
```

The simple solution to this is to move `inherit qmake5` before your `do_install`.

Also, here is the version of the recipe that uses the git URL instead of local files:

```
SUMMARY = "Qt Simple Calculator Application Recipe"   
DESCRIPTION = "This recipe builds a Qt project for a simple calculator application."   
LICENSE = "MIT"   
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"   
     
DEPENDS += "qtbase"   

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/vpapadopou/qt-simple-calculator.git;protocol=https;branch=master"
SRCREV = "1af09d43f9a41ad3136a4fac9db63b9542692f91"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"   

inherit qmake5
     
do_install() {   
    install -d ${D}/opt/qtsimplecalc/   
    install -m 0755 simpleCalculator ${D}/opt/qtsimplecalc/   
}   
    
FILES:${PN} += "/opt/qtsimplecalc/simpleCalculator"
```

You can check the `do_install` script `run.do_install` under `${WORKDIR}/temp`.

To make the install process handled by `qmake`, you can add the following to `simpleCalculator.pro` file:

```
target.path += /opt/qtsimplecalc/
INSTALLS += target
```

and then remove your custom `do_install` task in the recipe.

This will activate the original `do_install` of the `qmake5` class that will trigger `make install` target which will have the following content:

```
####### Install

install_target: first FORCE
    @test -d $(INSTALL_ROOT)/opt/qtsimplecalc/ || mkdir -p $(INSTALL_ROOT)/opt/qtsimplecalc/
    $(QINSTALL_PROGRAM) $(QMAKE_TARGET) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/opt/qtsimplecalc/$(QMAKE_TARGET)
    -$(STRIP) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/opt/qtsimplecalc/$(QMAKE_TARGET)

uninstall_target: FORCE
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/opt/qtsimplecalc/$(QMAKE_TARGET)
    -$(DEL_DIR) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/opt/qtsimplecalc/ 


install: install_target  FORCE

uninstall: uninstall_target  FORCE

FORCE:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Talel for the detailed explanation